# Why does batch script keep exiting after set /P user prompt?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls

echo Hello, there! Today is
date /t
echo and the current time is 
time /t

echo I'm so glad to meet you. My name is Hal 10000.
set /p name=What's your name?

cls

echo Well hello, %name%
echo Hey, %name%, & set /p "age"="how old are you in years?"
echo Well that's just great! I'm actually 115 today.
echo I look pretty good, huh!?
echo Well, gotta go, by!

exit
```

Comment: You're not 115. I was 8 when you were born in 1968 the year before Apollo 11. If you were 115 you'd be infected with Malware-Cov-2 virus.

Comment: Remove the `exit` statement which causes the window to exit. If you want to exit after a prompt, use `pause` instead of exit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a **pause** command. Your code is executing correctly but there is nothing stopping the code from exiting before you see your results.

```
@Echo off
Echo This message will not be displayed.
cls
Echo This message will be displayed.
pause
exit
```

Adding a **pause** before the **exit** will show your results until a button is pressed.